# Is it possible to integrate React.js app into existing native iOS project?

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift

I'm trying to integrate a **React.js** application into my native iOS project. I couldn't find an article on how to do it since most of the articles that I found are about how to integrate a **React Native** project into an existing iOS project (for example, [the official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps/)).

I tried to follow the steps but I always get this error whenever I install the pods after running `npm install` for the React.js project using Terminal:

> [!] Invalid Podfile' file: cannot load such file - - /.../the-react-js-project/node modules/react-native/scripts/react native _pods.

I was wondering if is it possible to integrate the React.js project using another way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.